# Add row base on condition of another column using Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, row, addition

I have a table and I want to add some rows based on column 'days'. And for each of those rows, the 'Date' column will increment by 1 day.

For example:
Table X:

| Date | Group | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 3 |
| 5/1/2023 | B | 4 |

I want the result like this:

| Date | Group | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 3 |
| 2/1/2023 | A | 3 |
| 3/1/2023 | A | 3 |
| 5/1/2023 | B | 4 |
| 6/1/2023 | B | 4 |
| 7/1/2023 | B | 4 |
| 8/1/2023 | B | 4 |

How can I do it in postgresql ? Please help me

I have tried and I realy don't know how to do it. I just a newbie too

Comment: Why should the 4th be skipped, how to know which is the last day? Should that last day be current day - one month? What is the day and what the month in your "date" column? Did you miss the leading zeros or should they be removed? Which datatype has this column?

Answer (score 0):

was:[image] became:[image]

You can call the function with the parameter of the number of rows you want to add:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertInfo(ZE int, need_date date default null) returns void AS
$$
BEGIN
if need_date is not null then
for z IN 1..ze  LOOP
insert into x ( your_date,your_group,your_days)
select need_date + interval '1' day, your_group,your_days+z from x
where  your_date = need_date;
end loop;
else
FOR i IN 1..ze LOOP
insert into x ( your_date,your_group,your_days)
select your_date + interval '1' day, your_group,your_days+1 from x
where  your_date = (select max(your_date) from x);
end loop;
end if;
END
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

if necessary date any count any quantity one parametr: `select insertInfo(1,'2023-01-01');`
if not necessary, just any quantity one parametr: `select insertInfo(1)`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` function with each incoming row to generate the dates appropriate for that row. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/naCRwc6r))

```
select (generate_series( xdate
                       , xdate + (xdays-1) * interval '1 day'
                       , interval '1 day'
                       )
        )::date "Date"
    , xgroup    "Group"
    , xdays     "Days" 
  from x;
```

Note: Each of your columns are poor choices for for names. They are all SQL Standard [reserved works](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and/or Postgres reserved/restricted. They can be used safely if double quoted (i.e. "Date") but then must be double quoted everywhere they are used. Avoid double quoting if all ll possible.  
When posting dates/timestamps to an international audience it is always best to use ISO 8601 Standard date format (yyyy-mm-dd). It is unambiguous regardless of your local format.